# Post shown as modified by Community in main page, but nothing modified..?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, community-user

while browsing the main page of stack overflow parent site, I noticed this:
[image]

However upon going to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516251/how-to-fix-request-querystring-before-pageload), I could not see anything modified in there. Am I getting blind, or is this some sort of weird bug? Why editing year old question anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user you see as "Community" is not a real person. It's a background process that helps keep Stack Overflow clean. One of the things it does is to randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention. In the above case, the question is quite old and still there is no accepted answer. Hence, "Community" poked it so it gets some attention.

Comment: [-1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)

Comment: Thanks, this surely solve the mystery. However, why not sending email to the OP telling him/her "Your question has pending answers, please mark one as correct"?

Comment: @aaronasterling - any idea why Mr. Community has so many up votes? Does it mean all questions get at least one up vote at some point??

Comment: Close -- it is lack of an *upvote* that triggers this though

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Mr. Community gets upvotes to Community Wiki posts. It is stated indirectly on [its user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community): "Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them". Second question: given infinite time most likely, in practice: no (Mr. Community is not the cause in either case).

Comment: "**Modified** by Community" is a very poorly chosen phrase, because people see that and expect to see... **modifications**.  A different term should be used.