# Community, what are you doing?

Tags: support

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/replace-special-characters-groups-of-characters-with-words-in-question-links) recently popped to the top of the active question queue. I spent some time reading the question, added some comments, and then realized that the last visible activity was *a month ago*.

To make sure I wasn't losing my mind, I returned to the Active queue to see if the question really had appeared there. I saw that the activity was generated by the Community user:

[image]

Since no edits appear on the question or answers, what is Community doing that causes the question to be considered "active?" For what it's worth, I have noticed the same behavior a handful of times before today.

Comment: The community user will "Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention" as one of its jobs. As described in its [profile page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: Also dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70184/152859).

Comment: question title is wrong, should be _Community, WTH are you doing?_ Or, maybe, even [WTH are you?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuuzipXwjnw)

Comment: @gnat I was tempted to go with: "[Community, wat r u doin? Community, stahp!](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/stahp)" but I resisted, mostly.

Comment: @gnat That link to YouTube no longer works.

Comment: @Peanut [use that link instead](https://youtu.be/xEvb7B4O698?t=37)

Comment: @gnat *heavy breathing*

Answer (score 5):

Community will [periodically "ping" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) that have no accepted answers and are older in order to provide the question with more visibility to improve the chance of an accepted answer.

Yes, Oded, I did borrow the link from your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The community user is controlled by our robot overlords who sometimes get a hankering to give stale unanswered questions some love. Anything that isn't downvoted to death, but hasn't gotten any answer love, is eligible for this periodic bump.

They do this by bumping the question to the home page.